# return error if scanf of a integer get a float or double

Tags: c, input, integer, double, scanf

I made a program in it that uses a scanf to receive values ​​and put them in an array.
the problem:
if I enter a double instead of an int, the program continues and converts the double to an int.
I want to do this scanf but if I receive 1.2 for example I return error of input and return 0;

```
if (!scanf("%d",&lst[i]) or (int)lst[i]==lst[i]){
         printf("error of input");
         return 0;}
```

dont work

Comment: You should read the input as string and parse that.

Comment: Since `lst` must be an array of `int` if the `scanf()` call is correct, the comparison `(lst[i] == lst[i]` will always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scanf` with `%s` format (or use another function) to write the characters that the user printed to a char buffer (e.g. `char buffer[256]`), and then you can turn it to an `int` using the `atoi` function.

Since you also want to check if the input contain anything else after the `int`, you can use `strtol` instead of `atoi`, since `atoi` is equivalent to `strtol(nptr, NULL, 10);` (according to the manual page). But, `strtol` has the advantage that it returns (via the `endptr` out-param) a pointer to the character that is after the last character that was parsed to `int`. In your case, I assume you expect this character to be `'\n'`, so you can simply check that, and if it is not `'\n'` then you can print an error.